# Index of/ not showing the text within files

Tags: ftp, ftp-client

I'm not a dev :/

Put my problem in pictures:

1. https://gyazo.com/44b10d458c40041d7710c9d424f8e9ce

As one can see I have contact.txt filled with my email, and it clearly containt text within it

2. https://gyazo.com/f1bb5359a233f9bebca0aa77ef308395

So I click on the txt file at my directory

And there nothing :/

Comment: What is the size of uploaded file after uploading?

Comment: Add more details in your post. What happens if those pages will be deleted? Your post will become useless.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache/history?

Comment: yes i just tried clearning the browser/history

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your file permissions you can see its current 0644, try 0755 and see if that helps.

Comment: your .htaccess file could be causing you issues possibly, depending whats inside. Do you have a link to the text file at all?

Comment: yes, the link works but none of the words are shown
http://joohee.pro/fbi/contact.txt

Comment: If you open up chrome dev tools you can see it results in a 404 error not found.

Comment: hmm
thanks for the info @aersol
didnt notice that before, gonna take a closer look at filezilla make sure its uploaded completely

Comment: Sorry I can't help any further thats about as far as my knowledge goes haha :) try logging in to your cpanel and view your file manager to see if you can view it through there. 

It could still possibly be caused by htaccess file, try clearing your htaccess file (back it up first) and see if that fixes any issues as well, if not just reupload the original.